# MySQL Query parsing two tables, two fields

Tags: mysql, sql

Database name = university

```
table1: university_info
field = university_name, student_number
e.g. values:

university_name          student_number
USC                      12345
USC                      54321
UW                       23456
UW                       65432

table2: student_info
field = student_number, student_test_scores
e.g. values:

student_number           student_test_scores
12345                    50
12345                    60
54321                    70
54321                    80
23456                    90
23456                    92
65432                    90
65432                    100
```

I have two tables above. Lets call the database university. I want to parse and output the university name, student number, and student test scores on the first query.

```
Example of first query:
e.g result
USC   12345   50
USC   12345   60
USC   54321   70
USC   54321   80
UW    23456   90
UW    23456   92
UW    65432   90
UW    65432  100
```

On the second query I want the same output but this time with the larger student test score.

```
Example of second query:
USC 12345  60
USC 54321  80
UW  23456  92
UW  65432 100
```

Once we have the highest student test scores we need to average the test scores in the third query and output the average of the highest student test scores.

```
Example of third query:
Average test scores = 83
```

---

Here is what I have so far on the second query. I couldn't figure out how to add the names:

```
mysql> select student_info.student_number, student_info.student_test_scores
    -> from student_info
    -> where (student_number='12345' and student_test_scores > 50)
    -> or (student_number='54321' and student_test_scores > 70)
    -> or (student_number='23456' and student_test_scores > 90)
    -> or (student_number='65432' and student_test_scores > 90)
    -> ;
+----------------+---------------------+
| student_number | student_test_scores |
+----------------+---------------------+
|          12345 |                  60 |
|          54321 |                  80 |
|          23456 |                  92 |
|          65432 |                 100 |
+----------------+---------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

I know there is a way better way of doing the 3 queries above. I just don't know how to do it. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cant understand third question

Comment: Time to learn about `JOIN`s and subqueries

Comment: why is this tagged as Oracle when it looks like you're working in mysql?

Comment: Oracle owns mysql or is a subparty of oracle I read it on there documentation page somewhere. I forget.

Comment: Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its affiliates. MySQL is a trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its affiliates, and shall not be used by Customer without Oracle's express written authorization. Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/introduction.html

Comment: On SO Oracle tags means Oracle DMBS, that is, the product. MySQL is another product, here another DBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL is very good at doing this.

You need to use the GROUP BY syntax, as well as, the aggregate functions MAX and AVG.

```
SELECT u.university_name, s.student_number, s.student_test_scores 
FROM student_info AS s
INNER JOIN university_info AS u ON s.student_number = u.student_number 
ORDER BY u.university_name, s.student_number, s.student_test_scores

SELECT u.university_name, s.student_number, MAX(s.student_test_scores) 
FROM student_info AS s
INNER JOIN university_info AS u ON s.student_number = u.student_number 
GROUP BY u.university_name, s.student_number
ORDER BY u.university_name, s.student_number

SELECT AVG(a.student_test_scores)
FROM (
    SELECT u.university_name, s.student_number, MAX(s.student_test_scores) AS student_test_scores
    FROM student_info AS s
    INNER JOIN university_info AS u ON s.student_number = u.student_number 
    GROUP BY u.university_name, s.student_number
) AS a
```

Comment: mysql> SELECT AVG(a.student_test_scores)
    -> FROM (
    ->     SELECT u.university_name, s.student_number, MAX(s.student_test_scores)
    ->     FROM student_info AS s
    ->     INNER JOIN university_info AS u ON s.student_number = u.student_number
    ->     GROUP BY u.university_name, s.student_number
    -> ) AS a;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'a.student_test_scores' in 'field list'
mysql>

Comment: That last edit did it... Wow I got a lot to learn lol... Thank you for the direction though. Time to study.

Comment: Can you answer one more question for me though. Why are you using u. in front of university_name and s. in front of student_number and a. in front of student_test_scores. What is that called so I can study it?

Comment: @Pepsi_1 - that means the the column alias is missing, so SQL can't resolve it. Adding "AS student_test_scores" to the proper column in the sub query resolves the issue. The error is fairly self explanatory "Unknown column 'a.student_test_scores' in 'field list'"

Comment: I aliased university_info and student_info to u and s, because it makes the SQL shorter and I don't like typing long table names out over and over again.